# maven hibernate SqlServer unable to load Class

Tags: hibernate, maven, sql-server-2012

When I try to connect to SQLServer with Maven, I have :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
```

In my POM.xml, driver for SQL Server and Hibernate are presents :

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.1.jre15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.30.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

This is content of my persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.2"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="connect" > 
        <properties> 
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databasename=warehouse"/> 
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" /> 
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value= "true"/> 
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/> 
        </properties> 
    </persistence-unit> 
</persistence>
```

When I look in the tree "Maven Dependencies", I have mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre15.jar. When I opened it, I see SQLServerDriver.class : it exists...

I don't understand why, when I run my app, it told me unable to load class SQLServerDriver

```
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("connect");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the dependency to your pom.xml will only make the JAR available to your build process, but not necessarily to the runtime. How do you run this main method? If you use `java -jar` then you have to understand that the JDBC driver will not be repackaged into your JAR file, so you would have to add it to the class path. You can use the exec-maven-plugin though if you want to run the main method with the dependencies from your pom.xml. See here for examples: https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html#Java_goal

Comment: Thank you very much, I was confused. I thought that with the driver in the POM, it would work: indeed, it had to be added to the class path.